# The requested URL [filename.php] was not found on this server

Tags: php, file-upload

```
    <?php
    echo "hello";   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/one1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

I have a Url on my server 
[This url is working. I have written echo "hello" in this.](http://www.medidenthealthcare.in/one1.php)

but when i go through [in this url i have written the html file upload code](http://www.medidenthealthcare.in/one.html)

It says The requested URL [one1.php]  was not found on this server.

I checked my file_upload is on.

Comment: It is file_uploads, not file_upload.

Comment: ok sorry for that
but that is ON i checked in my phpinfo();

Comment: well, in that case i think you should check if your temporary directory is writeable.

Comment: How can I check that? where to locate the tmp file

Comment: Chck this site: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your '**action**' attribute on **form** tag is set to **/one1.php**

Comment: The form action is working when i am not trying to upload the file, when it comes to upload the same problem is there

Comment: Maybe you have defined a route for GET method only? I don't know which framework you're using (if you're using any).

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="/one1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I contact the hosting team. They told to off the mod security in my panel and things the worked.